# Erro en la definición del TexBox en ASP.net

Tags: asp.net

Me sale el siguiente error cuando intento definir el tipo de caja de texto en un formulario hecho en ASP.net:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí parte del código del formulario:

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl_correlec" runat="server" Text="Correo Electrónico: "></asp:Label>
   <asp:TextBox ID="txt_correlec" runat="server" TextMode="Email"></asp:TextBox><br />

<asp:Label ID="lbl_fecnac" runat="server" Text="Fecha de Nacimiento (dd/mm/aaaa): "></asp:Label>
   <asp:TextBox ID="txt_fecnac" runat="server" TextMode="DateTime"></asp:TextBox><br />
```

Datos adicionales sobre el Netframework y propiedades del proyecto:

***Versión del Visual Studio:***
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Propiedades del Proyecto:***
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Propiedades del WebConfig:***
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La razón por la cual les envío imágenes con respecto al NetFramework es por que leí por ahí que solo la última versión soporta el origen del problema que les expongo en la primera línea, pero no lo entiendo, salvo el Visual Studio, todo está al día. Espero me ayuden averiguar la solución. Gracias

Comment: una consulta has puesto esto debajo del body
<form id="form1" server="runat" >

aqui los textox ? 
</form>

o en todo caso nos podrias mandar todo el body

Comment: Así es, todo está en orden, salvo ese par de cambios que hice en las cajas de texto que me terminó por arrojar esos dos errores.

Comment: @Franj, una consulta para que pones TextMode

Comment: TextBox tx = new TextBox();
txt.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;

Comment: veo que el problema es por el texboxmode
Prueba con esa que te puse . @Fran.J

Comment: El `TexMode` se añadió cuando modifiqué en la ventana de propiedades del objeto el parámetro con el mismo nombre por `Email`. Hay más opciones obviamente, por defecto es `SingleLine`, pero no tuve problemas cuando cambié en las demás cajas por el `MultiLine` y `Password`.

Comment: probaste con el codigo que te pase como comentario ?
en el codebign tienes que poner.
en el html borra TextMode="Email"  y  TextMode="DateTime"
TextBox tx = new TextBox(); txt.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;